# How to pipe file into `egrep`?

Tags: unix, terminal, grep

I'm trying to get the hang of how to use `egrep` to count occurrences of something in a file.

If I have a file like this, called `myfile`:

```
commas and stuff
more things
```

Then I'm able to count the number of o's in the first like by :

```
head myfile | egrep -c "o" myfile
```

For some reason, I am not able to do this with pipes.  If I have a file like this called `mypipes`:

```
| my | pipes |
```

I tried this:

```
head mypipes | egrep -c "|" mypipes
```

That gives me an error `empty sub(expression)`, so I tried the following:

```
head mypipes | egrep -c "\|" mypipes
```

This gives me a value of "1", which is clearly wrong.

How do I do this correctly? a full explanation rather than a one-off solution would be phenomenal.  thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `head` makes no sense.

Comment: Note that `egrep` ignores its standard input when you specify a file name on its command line.  Thie `egrep -c o myfile` causes `egrep` to read `myfile` directly and to ignore its standard input.  You can make it read standard input by specifying a 'file name' of just `-` or using `/dev/stdin`.  Thus: `egrep -c o myfile -` or `grep -Ec o myfile /dev/stdin`.  With no files specified, it reads standard input — that's the 'filter' idiom for Unix commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual:

```
-c, --count
      Suppress  normal output;
      instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.
```

You're counting the lines, not the characters.

```
egrep -o '\|' | wc -l
```

Note: You either feed the input (e.g.: pipe), or specify the file you want to search in. Why do you do both?

Comment: Consider using grep in place of egrep for a simpler regex: `grep -o '|' mypipes | wc -l`.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you've constructed, there is no need to pipe data to `egrep` because you're already telling it to read directly from a file.

If you don't provide a filename, `egrep` will read from STDIN instead:

```
head mypipes | egrep -c "\|"
```

As for your other question...

> This gives me a value of "1", which is clearly wrong.

Is it? `egrep -c` counts the number of lines that match, which in this case is 1.

If you want to count occurences, ignoring lines, this might help: [Count total number of occurrences using grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6979/count-total-number-of-occurrences-using-grep)